# Resize the text in \rput

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I use `\rput[B](4.0,0.5){text}` inside `pspicture` to write a text at a specific position. The text is too long, and I need to shrink its size, make it smaller, could anyone help?

Comment: Cool that works... By the way, do you know how to split the `text` to 2 rows, i.e. add a "new line"? `\\\` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in the argument to `\rput` is typeset in a `\mbox`, so everything that can go there is valid. For instance you can use font size changing commands such as `\footnotesize`:

```
\rput[B](4.0,0.5){\footnotesize text}
```

will typeset "text" in a reduced size.

For splitting the text across two lines you can use a `tabular`:

```
\rput[B](4.0,0.5){\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}line 1\\line 2\end{tabular}}
```

Use the optional argument `[t]` or `[b]` or no option if you want vertical alignment to the top line, bottom line or center respectively.

A font size changing command before `\begin{tabular}` will be obeyed.

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me what `{@{}l@{}}` means?

Comment: @SoftTimur No padding at the left (`@{}`), one column left aligned (`l`), no padding at the right (`@{}`).