# How to add two lines for \rput in radar chart

Tags: xetex, pstricks, charts

I'm able to draw radar chart using code mentioned below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\degrees[270]
\psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psaxes[dx=1,dy=1,Dx=25,Dy=25](0,0)(0,0)(4,4)%
\degrees[360]
\psxTick{0}(-1){25}
\psxTick{0}(-2){50}
\psxTick{0}(-3){75}
\psxTick{0}(-4){100}
\psyTick{0}(-1){25}
\psyTick{0}(-2){50}
\psyTick{0}(-3){75}
\psyTick{0}(-4){100}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!10]{\pskilla}{0}{40}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!50]{\pskillb}{40}{80}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!90]{\pskillc}{80}{120}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!10]{\pskilld}{120}{160}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!50]{\pskille}{160}{200}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!90]{\pskillf}{200}{240}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!10]{\pskillg}{240}{280}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!50]{\pskilli}{280}{320}
\pswedge[fillcolor=black!90]{\pskillj}{320}{360}
\rput(4.9;20){Skill 1 }
\rput(4.9;60){Skill 2}
\rput(4.9;100){Skill 3}
\rput(4.9;140){Skill 4}
\rput(4.9;180){Skill 5}
\rput(4.9;220){Skill 6}
\rput(4.9;260){Skill 7}
\rput(4.9;300){Skill 9}
\rput(4.9;340){Skill 10}
\psset{opacity=1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
```

Modification is required in this chart to add wordings as mentioned below
[image]
After every skill;  want to display percentage below it. Kindly suggest.

Comment: You can use a `\parbox` or a `tabular` inside the argument to `\rput`, as shown [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101310/text-alignment-in-paragraph-box) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100380/resize-the-text-in-rput).

Comment: Or a `\stackunder` from the `stackengine` package, as it erquires less typing.